# only gets the last value from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have a code,which need to display the label for the values same in the database to the data entered in the entry box.But i get only the last value of the label displayed not the first value.

Database:

```
a1 bike  
a2 car
```

Problem:If I enter a1,the bike not displayed..but i get car when a2 is entered.

Coding:

```
import Tkinter as tki
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT A1,A2 FROM adarsh1")
keywords1=[]
for i in cursor.fetchall():
    keywords1.append(i[0])
    keywords1.append(i[1])

class App(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
         self.root = root

         self.txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
         self.txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         button3 = tki.Button(self.txt_frm,text="CLICK 1", command = self.retrieve_inpu)
         button3.grid(column=0,row=2)
         self.entry = tki.Entry(self.txt_frm)
         self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0)

         #create label in init
         self.label = tki.Label(self.txt_frm)
         self.label.grid(column=0,row=3)

     def retrieve_inpu(self):
        ent = self.entry.get()

        if ent in i[0]:   
            self.label['text'] = i[1]


root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `i` as a loop variable when building `keywords1`:

```
for i in cursor.fetchall():
    keywords1.append(i[0])
    keywords1.append(i[1])
```

`i` is never cleared, it remains bound to the last row from the database.

You then re-use that global name:

```
def retrieve_inpu(self):
    ent = self.entry.get()

    if ent in i[0]:   
        self.label['text'] = i[1]
```

Since `i` is still set to `['a2', 'car']` the above `if` statement will only ever be true if `ent` is set to one of `'a2'`, `'a'`, or `'2'`.

You could instead use a *dictionary*:

```
keywords1 = {}
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    keywords1[row[0]] = row[1]
```

Now you are mapping values from the first column to the second. In your `retrieve_inpu` function you can now simply look up the value if the key exists:

```
def retrieve_inpu(self):
    ent = self.entry.get()

    if ent in keywords1:   
        self.label['text'] = keywords1[ent]
```

This would only match *whole words*, so only `'a2'` or `'a1'` would do.

The best method would be to ask the database for a match instead:

```
def retrieve_inpu(self):
    ent = self.entry.get()

    cursor.execute('SELECT A2 FROM adarsh1 WHERE A1=%s', (ent,))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row:
        self.label['text'] = row[0]
```

This again matches only on whole words; only if there is a row with an exact match for A1 can that row be returned. To make this work for substring matches, you can use a `LIKE` query:

```
def retrieve_inpu(self):
    ent = self.entry.get()

    cursor.execute('SELECT A2 FROM adarsh1 WHERE A1 LIKE %s', ('%{}%'.format(ent),))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row:
        self.label['text'] = row[0]
```